# How can I load javascript when the wasm in it, completely loaded

Tags: javascript, html, webassembly

Before starting, Sorry for my poor english..

I have encountered some problems using javascript that contains web assembly module load.

I created mobile keypad based on rust, and builded it wasm-pack.

This is my Web-pack build option.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "result.js",
        webassemblyModuleFilename: "MyModule.wasm",
        library: 'MyModule',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: ['default'],
        globalObject: 'this',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
...
}
```

my index.js

```js
import KeyPad from "./keypad";

export  default KeyPad;
export {
    KeyPad
};

global.KEYPAD = KeyPad;
```

my keypad.js

```
import * as core from '../pkg/~';
import '../css/style.css';
export default class KeyPad {
    some methods...
}
```

After build, I could get wasm files and build it again with command "npm run build" to get javascript file contains wasm.

After all of previous procedure, I created html file using the result javascript file, and called function.

```html
 <script src="./dist/result.js"></script>
 <script type="application/javascript">
    $(() => {
      console.log("globalVar = " + window.MyModule);
      let myModule = new MyModule({});
      myModule.showKey();
    })
  </script>
```

But I encountered Undefined error, however I refreshed the web site then I can get correct result.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyModule is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((색인):14:21)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30038)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30340)
(
```

After refresh, works well!

```
globalVar = class B{}
```

To solve this problem, I analyzed result javascript file, then I found syntax fetch('${MyModule.wasm}).

It seems to be a problem caused by loading wasm asynchronously in result javascript.

So the javascript file is loaded, but wasm is not fully loaded in javascript. As a result, Undefined Error but refreshing the web site -> fully loaded wasm file -> get works normally

I want to solve undefined error. How can i solve this problem??

Sorry again for my Poor English..

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the entire code? The solution here seems to be to wait for the resource to load, and this is usually done in html by adding the `defer` keyword to the `<script>` tag. Something like:

```html
 <script src="./dist/result.js"></script>
 <script defer type="application/javascript">
    $(() => {
      console.log("globalVar = " + window.MyModule);
      let myModule = new MyModule({});
      myModule.showKey();
    })
  </script>
```

Anyway, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878) is a stackoverflow question with multiple suggestions for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting, I added entire code on my question. Can you check it again?